# Copy MBR and boot partition to a smaller disk

Tags: dd, raspberry-pi, fdisk, mbr

I'm using a 32GB SD card for my raspberry pi. I have successfully transferred the operating system (`Archlinux` `ARM`) to a usb harddrive. Which means that I only need the boot partition on the SD card.

A 32GB card that only uses about 100MB is an awful waste of space and I do have a smaller SD card with 4GB around.

How do I copy the `MBR` and the first partition of the 32GB card to the 4GB card?

I've tried saving the `MBR` and the first partition of the bigger card with `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=mbr_image bs=446 count=1
dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=boot_image
```

I then created a new partition table on the smaller card
that looks exactly like the table on the original 32GB card:

```
Device    Boot Start       End Blocks  Id System
/dev/sdc1 *     2048    194559  96256  c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Finally I copied the previously stored images onto my smaller card:

```
dd if=mbr_image of=/dev/sdc bs=446 count=1
dd if=boot_image of=/dev/sdc1
```

Everything looks fine in `fdisk` but it does not work. 
My raspberry doesn't do anything when I try to boot from the smaller card.

Where is the error?

Comment: ARM systems like the rasberry pi do not have bios, and do not boot using an MBR.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. But if the MBR is not the problem what is? I've read that is just looks for specific files inside the first partition which of course are the same on both SD cards.

Comment: You may need to force the kernel reload the MBR after modifying it: `hdparm -z /dev/sdc` before accessing /dev/sdc1

Answer (score 1):

In my case I've been having trouble just copying MBR. For me the next steps worked:

1. `fdisk` the new card with the partitions you want.
2. Mount the new card and `cp` the partition files you want (I guess it is just boot partition) from the old one to the new one. Modify (in case
   you're using grub2) `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` in the new card so that
   the UUID of the boot partition is now the one of your 4GB card (use
   `blkid` to identify the UUID).
3. Start the system with the 32GB card and mount the 4GB card.
4. `mount --bind` /dev, /proc and /sys from the old card to the new
   one.
5. `chroot` to the mounted 4GB card.
6. `grub-install` to your 4GB card.

EDIT:
Steps 4-6 can be replaced by `grub-install --boot-directory=YourPathToMounted4GBBoot /dev/your4GBcard`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this instructional](http://ddurdle.blogspot.com/2014/01/re-purposing-old-sd-cards-for-booting.html) when backing up the MBR you want to use `bs=512` and then `bs=446` when copying it to the smaller card.

```
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=mbr_image bs=512 count=1
dd if=mbr_image of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=446 count=1
```

I have no hands-on experience with Raspberry Pi so I don't know if the device label matters.  The [referenced site](http://ddurdle.blogspot.com/2014/01/re-purposing-old-sd-cards-for-booting.html) suggests using `/dev/mmcblk0` for the MBR and `/dev/mmcblk01` for the device partition.

EDIT:

I overlooked this before.  The steps you tried and the link I mentioned both seem to be lacking the file system formatting.  After creating `/dev/sdc1` using fdisk, you will need to format the file system before it will be usable.

```
mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdc1
```

After this, execute `dd if=boot_image of=/dev/sdc1` and it should work.

Comment: Those are not labels but the names given by system. They are called /dev/sd* in my example because I mounted the cards on another PC. When a card is plugged in my rpi the partitions are called differently, hence the /dev/mmcblk* names in the instructional.

Comment: The commands you quote from the instructional end up doing exactly what I'm doing already btw. Just that I don't save the partition table in the first place.